# Do gravitating bodies emit dark matter?

Tags: general-relativity, gravity, newtonian-gravity

One way to generate dark matter halos surrounding galaxies is to assume the Schwarzschild radius of a star (mass $M$) is the norm of a complex oscillator: $$\pmb{r_{s}}(t) = r_{s}\boldsymbol{\hat{r}} e^{i\omega t} $$
A time derivative determines the velocity of the radius vector $\pmb{v} = i\omega r_s\boldsymbol{\hat{r}}\cdot e^{i\omega t}$ which can be viewed as the boundary of associated velocity and compression fields radiating at light speed:
\begin{align} \pmb{v}(r,t) & = \frac{i\omega r_s^2}{r}\cdot e^{i\omega(t-r/c 
+\tau_s)} & p(r,t) =\frac{p_o}{c}||\pmb{v}(r,t)|| \end{align}
While there seems to be no medium associated with these fields, a familiar formula from continuum mechanics produces a time-averaged dark energy flux
$$\pmb{S}_D(r) = \frac{1}{2}p^* \pmb{v} = \frac{\alpha Mc^3}{4\pi r^2}\boldsymbol{\hat{r}}$$  In this equation the unknown constant $\alpha$ has units of inverse-length and the constants $\omega$ and $p_o$ are chosen to be $\omega = \sqrt{\alpha/r_s} c$ and $p_o = Mc^2/2\pi r_s^3$.

Of course this theory only makes sense if one assumes that the dark flux represents a continuous violation of conservation of energy.  In other words, oscillations of $r_s$ are god-given, and the power output remains steady at $P_D = \alpha Mc^3$ unless other energy conserving processes act to change $M$.  Ultimately, the consequence of energy violation and the equivalence of mass and energy via $E=mc^2$ is to replace the conventional mass with a radial mass field $$M(r) = M(1+\alpha r)$$ and this mass field can be inserted directly into the Newtonian gravitational force law leading to a re-fashioned field $$\pmb{g_{net}} = -GM\left[\frac{1}{r^2} + \frac{\alpha}{r}\right] \boldsymbol{\hat{r}}=\pmb{g} + \pmb{g}_\alpha$$

Let's assume $\alpha \sim 10^{-20}$ m$^{-1}$ which defines it as a far field constant of the universe.  For local measurements in the neighborhood of a solar system the presence of $\alpha$ will be difficult to detect.  However, in the far field limit, the Newtonian term makes no contribution and velocities of large orbit test-bodies become $$ v=\sqrt{\alpha GM} $$ Now extend this result to galactic scales with billions of stars, adjust $\alpha$ accordingly, and arrive at a galaxy with a dark matter halo.  Is there experimental evidence to suggest that a theory of gravitating bodies emitting dark energy is incorrect? Moreover, can this theory be derived as a weak field limit of general relativity with a dark source?

Comment: At two points in this question you referred to "dark energy" rather than "dark matter". Is this a mistake, or did I misunderstand what your intent was?

Comment: Personal theories are [off-topic](https://physics.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) on this site.

Comment: A normal star doesn't have a Schwarzschild radius to begin with.

Comment: @FlatterMann Well, it does. It's just bigger than it.

Comment: @LoganJ.Fisher Of course you can calculate such a quantity, it just doesn't have any physical meaning. The Schwarzschild radius of a black hole is observable (even though it is only well defined for an observer resting at infinity), but absolutely nothing observable happens at the Schwarzschild radius of a star that hasn't collapsed.

Comment: Right. It's more just a matter of mathematical curiosity.

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like you're discussing [MOND](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Modified_Newtonian_dynamics) here. This has been essentially ruled out (although it still has some defenders) by the [bullet cluster](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bullet_Cluster).

Simply put, as the gravitational lensing of the bullet cluster doesn't align with the location of the Baryonic matter, we can't model dark matter as being due to the Baryonic matter. Rather, it must be its own distinct kind of matter.

Comment: I have thought for a long time that, from the perspective of modified gravity, the dark matter of the Bullet Cluster could just be particles from the modified gravitational field - massive gravitons, bound states of gravitons, and so on. For some reason I can't find or remember a systematic discussion of this possibility, though maybe it has just slipped my mind... I know there's an attempt to explain the Bullet Cluster using MOND plus sterile neutrinos, see section 7.1 of https://arxiv.org/abs/2110.06936

Answer (score 1):

If I try to understand what you're proposing... You're saying that even for an object whose density is too low to create an event horizon, inside it there is a dark sphere with radius equal to the Schwarzschild radius, there's some kind of cyclic process at the surface of this sphere, some kind of flux spreads outwards from the surface, and the energy of this flux creates the dark-matter density profile of a galaxy.

Surely it's possible to create a model that behaves like this, but it may require some intricate mechanisms. What is that dark sphere, for example? Is it a condensate of gravitons? Maybe a condensate of gravitons from a second metric? (The MOND literature contains many examples of 'bimetric' theories.)

I suggest you contact someone who works on modified gravity, and try to make a full-fledged model.